# meta does not work as expected and without meta things look better

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am in the middle of my design and I just want to make sure I am on the right path.
I am using bootstrap and I do need my design to be responsive. I designed a simple lay out as follows and everything is what I want when I check it in chrome toggle device toolbar. My code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<title>ReactJS Basics</title>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet"
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
integrity="sha384- BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"
crossorigin="anonymous">

 <!-- Optional theme -->
 <link rel="stylesheet"
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"
integrity="sha384- rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp"
crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">   </script>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
 <script
src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"
integrity="sha384- Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa"
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


 <style>
 /*----------------------HEADER --------------------------------------------   -------------  */
 .header {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #4070CB;
  color: #EFF0F2;
  height: 100px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  }

 .col {
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
 }

   .header a {
    color: white;
   font-size: 5vw;
   }

  .txt-align-right {
    text-align: right;
 }

  .txt-align-left {
    text-align: left;
   }

   .txt {
     align-items: center;
     display: flex;
     text-align: center;
     justify-content: center;
    }

    .font-size-xs {
      font-size: 4vw;
   }
   </style>
   </head>
    <body>
<div id="mainContainer" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 header">
            <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 txt-align-left">
                <a href="#"> <!-- react-text: 7 --> <!-- /react-text --> <span
                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 txt font-size-xs">TEST For PRACTICE</div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 txt-align-right">
                <a href="#"> <!-- react-text: 12 --> <!-- /react-text --> <span
                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-3 col-lg-3 color1">
            <div class="row"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-4 col-lg-4 color2">test</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-3 col-lg-3 color1">.col-sm-4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But since I see that in different posts people suggest to use meta tag I added the following meta in my page:

```
<meta name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
```

But as soon as I add the above meta there are some changes in the look of my header which is not what I want. Now my question is when my page looks good on different views using toggle device toolbar of chrome do I have to use meta ? Or can I just ignore it ?  I am thinking may be because I am using bootsrap it already take what ever meta does in to account and I do not need to use meta, am I right?

Comment: On this site, I haven't seen many people recommend `user-scalable=no`. Anyway, are you saying you only test mobile views on a desktop Chrome? If so, know that Chrome's emulator is far from perfect. You only need to worry if the site looks bad on a real phone.

Comment: @MrLister Thanks. So this way if I do not rely on emulator,  I should publish my page all the time and check it with different mobile devices. Is it the way you recommend? Also, Ifrom your comment I assume that you suggest using meta tag, am I right?

Comment: Yes, unless you want to maintain two separate websites for mobile and desktop devices, you can't really do without the meta. But its parameters depend on what your needs are. If you want the site to look on a phone like a desktop browser with its window made very small and narrow, the minimum required would be `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">`. Then display your page on a phone (a real one) and see if it works as desired or if you need other parameters as well.

Comment: @MrLister Thanks you exactly pointed at what my problem is since as soon as I add width=device-width" it messes up the page and without that everything looks good since I used bootstrap carefully to take care of the design. So can I easily ignore that parameter and rely what I have achieved with bootstrap(though still I use meta tag but without device width param)?

Comment: Can you provide more insight in how it looks wrong? Screenshots before and after?

Comment: @MrLister  Thanks and sure please take a look at this : http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FB7U2AVWZ5MX  if you try it with iphone 5 or 4 you can see that when we have meta, the 12 grid ssytem does not fit the row. Also please find more explanation of my problem here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41363321/bootstrap-grid-system-does-not-work-on-all-devices-size